# UPDATE a value and then ORDER BY

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to update a value on a table and then order the table again.
I'm doing this query:

```
UPDATE classifier 
SET crimeCount = crimeCount + 1 
WHERE zoneID = $1 ORDER BY zoneid;
```

But it said "ERROR: syntax error"

What is the problem?

Comment: You dont order an `update`, because update doesnt return any result. If you look the [**MANUAL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html) you wont see any place to put `ORDER BY`

Comment: `ORDER BY` isn't part of an `UPDATE` statement, it's part of a `SELECT` statement. Don't think of data in a table as having a specific order.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because tables are not ordered.  If you want the table returned in a particular order, then use `select . . . order by`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are not ordered.
you can get a result set ordered by using `ORDER BY` in your select query, but you can't order a table, there's no such thing